# Where to start to learn how to build Linux GUI apps based on scripts?

Tags: linux, user-interface

First off, I'm looking to write GUI apps based on an interpreted language (PHP if possible--otherwise, Python). Second, I'm looking for a rapid-app GUI designer that lets me create windows, drop UI elements on it, and wire those elements up to code easily. Finally, it would be nice to have a simple way to package the whole thing up (deb, rpm, etc). Ideally my application should work on any Linux platform, and in Gnome or KDE.

I'm wondering if Glade is the way to go? And do I install just "glade" (via APT) or "glade-gnome"? (I'm on Linux Mint 10)

Bonus question: it would be cool to be able to have code that I could very easily just port over to Windows & Mac OS and work as well (UI and all). Of course, I'm thinking Python is probably the way to go as the underlying language.. if I recall correctly, Python has some way to build UIs that work on any platform? I could be wrong.

EDIT: Again, I have to say.. it is important to be able to have an interface designer of sorts. I absolutely do not want to code windows, buttons, input boxes, etc., by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd really suggest you have a look at Qt. You have Python GPL ([PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/news)) bindings available or the (newer) LGPL [Pyside](http://www.pyside.org/) bindings readily available:

- A mature, stable, well documented and extremely rich framework
- Comes with a GUI Designer for easy drag and drop UI design
- Cross platform for free (Windows, Linux, Mac)

Comment: Cool, I will give it a look. Curious no one else has answered this Q.. I guess all the Linux geeks are out to lunch. ;)

Comment: what about a user interface designer where I can create windows, drag/drop UI elements, etc?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: that's included in QT (and PyQt)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)